# Where Clause in LINQ with IN operator in Vb

Tags: vb.net, linq, where-in

To get details of a person 'Adam' Sql query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Name = 'Adam'
```

Linq query in Vb

```
From tableName In something Where row.Field(Of String)("name").Trim = "Adam"
```

But to get details of multiple people 'Adam', 'Chris' Sql query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Name IN ('Adam', 'Chris')
```

Linq query in VB???

Edited:
Linq query in VB is

From tableName In something Where {"Adam", "Chris"}.Contains(row.Field(Of String)("name").Trim)

Comment: I think it's something like `From tableName In something Where {"Adam", "Chris"}.Contains(row.Field(Of String)("name").Trim)` - making use of [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Awesome this worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cool - added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim item= From tableName In something
               where {"Adam", "Chris" }.Contains(u.something)
               select i
```

Try this code

Comment: Yeah and "new[]" is not required in Vb

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), e.g. with an array of the values you are looking for:

```
Dim dt = New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John")
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Adam")
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Chris")

Dim values = {"Adam", "Chris"}
Dim results =
    From row In dt
    Where values.Contains(row.Field(Of String)("Name").Trim)
For Each row In results
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", row.Field(Of Integer)("ID"), row.Field(Of String)("Name"))
Next
```

Output:

```
2 - Adam
3 - Chris
```